# function is multiplicative

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, multiplicative-function

Consider

$ f(n) =
  \begin{cases}
    0       & \quad \text{if } n \text{ is even}\\
    1       & \quad \text{if } n \equiv 1  \text{ mod } 4\\
    -1      & \quad \text{if } n \equiv -1  \text{ mod } 4
  \end{cases}
$

How is it possible to show then that $f(.)$ is multiplicative ?

Comment: Use the definition. Assume $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, show $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$.

Comment: It’s more than multiplicative, $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$ for any $m,n$, not just when $\gcd(m,n)=1.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that, you have to consider the different cases and the compatibility of product with the $\equiv [4]$ relation. If $n \equiv x[4]$ and $m \equiv y [4]$, then $nm \equiv xy [4]$. So:

- If $n$ or $m$ are even then their product also. Then $f(nm)=0=f(n)f(m)$
- If $x=1$ and $y=1$, Then $f(nm)= 1 = f(n)f(m)$
- If $x=1$ and $y=-1$ or $x=-1$ and $y=1$ , Then $f(nm)= -1 = f(n)f(m)$
- If $x=-1$ and $y=-1$, Then $f(nm)= 1 = (-1)^2= f(n)f(m)$